# Nintendo Switch output into my computer is fuzzy

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have a very strange issue. I want to plug an AUX cord into my Nintendo Switch and then treat it as a line into my computer. The odd thing is, I know everything works.

1. Audio from my phone into my computer is fine. This tells me the cable works and my computer input works.
2. If I plug my headphones directly into the switch, it works. This tells me the switch output is fine.

So if my computer input, switch output, and cable work, what could be causing the issue. Keep in mind I did not change the headphones so they work.

edit - I took the Switch off the dock and the audio worked. Therefore, the dock is causing the issue.

edit 2 - So then I unplugged the HDMI from the dock and it worked so the HDMI was causing the issue. Is it possible for the HDMI to interfere with Audio and if so, what fixes are there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect a headphone jack to a line-in jack you are most likely over driving the pre-amp circuit in the computer. Headphone jacks and line-in jacks are not compatible.

One is meant to drive a low impedance, high wattage, relatively high-voltage load (a headphone speaker) and the other is a high-impedance, low-voltage line-level input.

If you want things to sound right you’re going to have to turn the volume down on the Nintendo until the sound is no longer distorted, then turn the volume up on the computer to make it louder.

Comment: What's odd is that when the switch is not connected to an HDMI, it works perfectly, which led me to my conclusion. I bought a ground noise isolator which some people online said fixed the problem,